# Patch Error 2229 for non-default languages in Windows Vista/7

Tags: windows-vista, windows-installer, installshield

I'm having a problem with a patch.  The patch supports English by default, as well as a few other languages.  When a non-English language is chosen while installing the patch in Windows Vista/7 error 2229 occurs referring to a failed SQL query to the CONTROL table. Any suggestions?

Comment: First guess is a character encoding issue. But you should put a little more information for people to be able to help you.

Comment: This forum thread looks interesting: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33613630/error-2229-when-initiatin.aspx